# Sharing core repository and object mapping logic between Unit of Work methods

Tags: c#, repository, unit-of-work

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this or if I'm doing some anti-pattern here. Like I say in the subject, I'm trying to share repository calls and object mapping logic between Unit of Work methods.

For example see my `GetEnvelopeBody()` method being used more than once.

```
public class EnvelopeService
{
    private EnvelopeRepository envelopeRepository;
    private RecipientRepository recipientRepository;
    private RecipientTabRepository recipientTabRepository;

    public Envelope GetEnvelope(int id)
    {
        using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            envelopeRepository = new EnvelopeRepository(uow);
            recipientRepository = new RecipientRepository(uow);
            recipientTabRepository = new RecipientTabRepository(uow);

            // I'm extracting the repository calls and mapping 
            // code into this GetEnvelopeBody() so other methods 
            // that have their own Unit of Work can use it.
            // This is to avoid multiple Unit of Work sessions? 
            // from colliding.
            var envelope = GetEnvelopeBody(id);

            uow.SaveChanges();

            return envelope;
        }
    }

    private Envelope GetEnvelopeBody(int id)
    {
        // repository calls and object mapping code goes here
    }

    public void SaveEnvelope(Envelope envelope)
    {
        using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            envelopeRepository = new EnvelopeRepository(uow);
            recipientRepository = new RecipientRepository(uow);
            recipientTabRepository = new RecipientTabRepository(uow);

            SaveEnvelopeBody(envelope);

            uow.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private void SaveEnvelopeBody(Envelope envelope)
    {
        CleanEnvelope(envelope);

        // repository calls and object mapping code goes here
    }

    private void CleanEnvelope(Envelope newEnvelope)
    {
        var oldEnvelope = this.GetEnvelopeBody(newEnvelope.Id);
        // Do other fancy stuff ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what's going on, or where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem I see is that your `EnvelopeService` class is not threadsafe.

Imagine two threads using a single instance of `EnvelopeService`.  **Thread 1** calls `GetEnvelope` which creates a `UnitOfWork`. At the same time **Thread 2** calls `SaveEnvelope` which creates a second `UnitOfWork`.  Whether those two operations are carried out using the appropriate `UnitOfWork` is not guaranteed.

This is because you're effectively storing your `UnitOfWork` at the class level (in your 3 repository instances) and then using it in subsequent helper method calls.  This is shared state and is unsafe.

A safer approach would be to remove the shared state:

```
public class EnvelopeService
{
        public Envelope GetEnvelope(int id)
        {
                using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
                {
                        var envelopeRepository = new EnvelopeRepository(uow);
                        var recipientRepository = new RecipientRepository(uow);
                        var recipientTabRepository = new RecipientTabRepository(uow);

                        var envelope = GetEnvelopeBody(id, envelopeRepository, recipientRepository, recipientTabRepository);

                        uow.SaveChanges();

                        return envelope;
                }
        }

        private Envelope GetEnvelopeBody(
            int id,
            EnvelopeRepository envelopeRepository,
            RecipientRepository recipientRepository,
            RecipientTabRepository recipientTabRepository)
        {
                // repository calls and object mapping code goes here
        }

        public void SaveEnvelope(Envelope envelope)
        {
                using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
                {
                        var envelopeRepository = new EnvelopeRepository(uow);
                        var recipientRepository = new RecipientRepository(uow);
                        var recipientTabRepository = new RecipientTabRepository(uow);

                        SaveEnvelopeBody(envelope, envelopeRepository, recipientRepository, recipientTabRepository);

                        uow.SaveChanges();
                }
        }

        private void SaveEnvelopeBody(
            Envelope envelope,
            EnvelopeRepository envelopeRepository,
            RecipientRepository recipientRepository,
            RecipientTabRepository recipientTabRepository)
        {
                CleanEnvelope(envelope, envelopeRepository, recipientRepository, recipientTabRepository);

                // repository calls and object mapping code goes here
        }

        private void CleanEnvelope(
            Envelope newEnvelope,
            EnvelopeRepository envelopeRepository,
            RecipientRepository recipientRepository,
            RecipientTabRepository recipientTabRepository)
        {
                var oldEnvelope = this.GetEnvelopeBody(newEnvelope.Id, envelopeRepository, recipientRepository, recipientTabRepository);
                // Do other fancy stuff ...
        }
}
```

Notice that the repositories holding your your `UnitOfWork` are now passed into your helper methods as dependencies.

Whether you should be `new`ing your repositories is another potential point of concern.  It might make testing the `EnvelopeService` class difficult.  Consider using a `Factory` to get your repository instances instead.  Then again, that might be overkill.  It really depends on your situation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the problem with thread safety out! The reason I made the repos properties on the class was to eventually unit test the service, thanks for recommending the use of a factory for that.